# "Style sheets that use relative units can more easily scale from one output environment to another"?

Tags: css, w3c

The CSS Spec has this statement when talking about relative units versus absolute units:

> Style sheets that use relative units **can more easily scale from one output environment to another**.

What does this mean and why is it true?

1. What does it mean to "more easily scale"?
2. What is the "output environment"?

#### "output environment"

Is this referring to the dpi of the screen? Or print media versus screen media? Or does it speak to UA custom stylesheets or text size adjustments for accessibility?

#### "more easily scale"

Does it mean that element sizes will stay ***relatively* consistent** when viewed on different screens with different dpis? I.e. that a `1rem` element and a `1.2rem` element will be the same relative size compared to each other across different screens, whereas a `14px` and a `16px` element will vary in size relative to each other? This doesn't seem true.

Or does this have to do with the **base font size**? I.e. since relative units are relative, they can scale relative to the base font size.

This assumes that a UA sets the base font size based on the dpi of the device's screen. The spec states that the base font size is an absolute value:

> When specified in the `font-size` property of the root element, `1rem` is equal to the initial value of the `font-size` property. [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem)

The initial `font-size` value is `medium`. [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-size-prop)

`medium` is an `absolute-size`, and these mappings are defined by the UA. [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#absolute-size-value)

So it makes sense to say that since **relative length units** can be based on the root font size, they can be influenced by the UA's decision about what the base font size should be.

But it's unclear why this is a good thing, compared to simply using the CSS pixel which should always be the same physical size (around 1/96"). Do some browsers break this rule and size a "CSS pixel" as much smaller, such as in the "desktop mode" of Chrome on Android?)

So if the base font size and the CSS pixel are both based on the dpi, and they both aim to display a consistent physical size, what's the advantage of using one or the other, unless there are some cases where a UA varies the root font size to *not* be a consistent physical size.

Comment: Absolute units don't scale; that's what absolute means. They are designed to be a reliable size, only changing when the environment literally doesn't support a given size. See https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html for more info.

Comment: There are two close votes calling this question opinion-based. Can the voters please explain this?

Comment: @TylerH I get what you're saying, but there is nuance because pixels do scale in two ways: with browser zoom, and in relation to dpi. So I would add the caveat: "absolute units don't scale _based on font size_". This seems to be the crux of the issue: `ems` and `rems` can scale based on ancestor font size, whereas pixels can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the google chrome setting page you can find the following:

[image]

You can update the `font-size` from `medium` to something else and this will have an effect only when using `rem` and `em` units.

If you consider only pixel value you will make that setting useless and people cannot increase the `font-size` of your website.